# Loop through child categories and output custom field on archive.php

Tags: wordpress, foreach, archive, advanced-custom-fields, taxonomy

I am using Wordpress and have categories with parent/child relationships.
I have used Advanced Custom Fields to add custom fields to the categories.

On the archive.php page I would like to show the title of each child category and a custom field form the child category. I am currently outputting the child categories title as below -

```
<?php $this_cat = get_query_var('cat');
wp_list_categories('child_of=' . $this_cat . '&title_li=&show_option_none=&depth=1&hide_title_if_empty=true');?>
```

Is there a way to either include the ability to also output the custom field, or a way to actually loop through the child categories and output the field?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a tax query to get the child categories, and then loop through them with wp query, something like this:

```
<?php

  $this_cat = get_query_var('cat');

$args = array(
    'tax_query' => [
         [
             'taxonomy' => 'category',
             'terms'    =>  $this_cat,
         ],
     ],
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

    //get your custom field
    $yourField = get_field( 'field_name' ); ?>

    <div>
        <?php echo $yourField ?>
    </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```